# Call method of parent class component from child class component

Tags: reactjs

I've got a method **addNotification()** at App.js which I want to reuse in some of my other components. Here I used **AgencyProfile** component for example. It doesn't work if I export the **addNotification()** method from **App.js**. How can I call the method **addNotification()** from other child components, here for example **AgencyProfile**? here is my App.js code

```
export class App extends React.Component{

.....

        addNotification(title, message, level, time) {
        let dismiss = (time === undefined) ? 0 : time;
        this.notification.addNotification({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            level: level,
            autoDismiss: dismiss
        });
    }
.......

render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <NotificationSystem ref={ref => this.notification = ref}/>
                <AgencyProfile />

            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible if you pass the function `addNotification` as a prop (callback) for the component in which you want to reuse the function as:

App.js:

```
export class App extends React.Component{

.....

addNotification = (title, message, level, time) => {
        let dismiss = (time === undefined) ? 0 : time;
        this.notification.addNotification({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            level: level,
            autoDismiss: dismiss
        });
    };

.......

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NotificationSystem ref={ref => this.notification = ref}/>
                <AgencyProfile onAddNotification={this.addNotification} />
                .....

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And in the child component we can just make a method like this to call **addNotification()** method in the **App.js**

AgencyProfile.js

```
showNotification(title, message, level, time){
    this.props.onAddNotification(title, message, level, time);
}
```

use this method to call **addNotification()** from anywhere inside **AgencyProfile** component.

Another approach is to make **addNotification()** a exportable function in another `js` file and them import it in the component where you want to use it (But with this approach you'll have to bind `this` depending on where you are going to use it):

```
import addNotification from 'helpers/addNotification';
```

Comment: thanks @Alberto for your answer, however I've made some changes in your answer to make it more relevant with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really export/import a function like that. If you don't want to pass it down the tree as a prop, your best bet will be to use react's context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. Then instead of importing a function, you will just get it from context.